# Perl IO::Socket::SSL connection error "SSL connect attempt failed error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group"

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm attempting to make an SSL connection to my STOMP server and I'm getting the error:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2554: new ctx 40724256
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:539: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:541: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:563: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:631: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:650: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=5
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:683: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:703: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2457: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:683: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:703: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2410: ok=1 cert=40749168
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2410: ok=1 cert=42073408
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1558: scheme=default cert=42073408
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:683: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:703: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1779: SSL connect attempt failed
SSL error:  20723: 1 - error:1408D010:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_KEY_EXCHANGE:EC lib

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1784: SSL connect attempt failed error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:669: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed error:100AE081:elliptic curve routines:EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name:unknown group
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1768: IO::Socket::IP configuration failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2587: free ctx 40724256 open=40724256
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2592: free ctx 40724256 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2599: OK free ctx 40724256
```

Module Versions:

> Net::SSLeay 1.66
>   IO::Socket::SSL 2.005
>   IO::Socket::IP 0.32
>   Net::Stomp 0.49
>   OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips (RHEL)

And the server I'm connecting to is running OpenSSL 1.0.1f (Ubuntu 14.04)

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be that your STOMP server has custom build for OpenSSL and configured for the special param set of elliptic curve. On Ubuntu setup default openssl that is not include those elliptic curve in build. Check your ec params on both servers, see https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ecparam.html

Comment: Check out https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2013-1751.html. Looks like your client announces support for EC ciphers it does not have.

Comment: The Ubuntu OpenSSL install is a stock apt install.   The current version of OpenSSL on the RHEL box is:
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 30.el6_6.2

Comment: Do you provide any ssl_options in your code?